# Merge sort generic method

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

My merge sort doesn't seem to be working correctly. When I display the sorted list, it is not sorted and elements are added, where there is supposed to be 9 there is 49. 
Anyone see where Im going wrong?

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void mergeSort(List<E> A) {
    int n = A.size();
    if (n > 1) {
        int half = n / 2;
        List<E> B = copyPartialArray(A, 0, half);
        List<E> C = copyPartialArray(A, half, n);
        mergeSort(B);
        mergeSort(C);
        merge(B, C, A);
    }
}

public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void merge(List<E> B, List<E> C, List<E> A) {
    int n1 = B.size();
    int n2 = C.size();
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (B.get(i).compareTo(C.get(j)) < 0) {
            A.add(k, B.get(i));
            i++;
        }
        else {
            A.add(k, C.get(j));
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    if (i == n1)
        for (int p = j; p < n2; p++) {
            A.add(k, C.get(p)); k++;
        }
    else if (j == n2)
        for (int p = i; p < n1; p++) {
            A.add(k, B.get(p)); k++;
        }
}

private static <E extends Comparable<E>> List<E> copyPartialArray(List<E> A, int first, int last) {
    int n = last - first;
    List<E> copy = new ArrayList<E>(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    copy.add(i, A.get(first + i));
    return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer will try to make you realise what's wrong.

It's clear that mergeSort won't do anything to a one element array, but what happens if there are two (for instance [2,1])? You mention there are more elements than before in the result list (list A). Why? What's merge doing to that list? [Hint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29).